# Jquery Autocomplete Unauthorized Webmethod

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-autocomplete, webmethod

I am attempting to use a jQuery autocomplete textbox to look up data from a database in WebForm (.NET 4.6).  When the AJAX method is fired, I am receiving a 401 Unauthorized error in the console.

Please let me know how to successfully hit the Webmethod on the serverside useing the jQuery autocomplete function.

My js file is as follows:

```
$(function() {

    ...

    $("input[id*='txtDiagnosisSearch']").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "/WebUserProvider/Referral_Precert_CNReferralForm.aspx/GetDiagnosisCodes",
                data: "{'diagCode':'" + $("input[id*='txtDiagnosisSearch']").val() +
                    "', 'description':'" + $("input[id*='txtDiagnosisSearch']").val() + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                    response(data.d);
                },
                error: function(result) {
                    alert("No Match");
                }
            });
        }
    });

    });
```

My HTML is as follows:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">

    <script src="../JavaScript/WebProvider/Referral_Precert_CNReferralForm.js"></script>

...

<div style="display: inline-block; font-weight: bold; width: 20%">
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtDiagnosisSearch"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>

...

</asp:Content>
```

And my server-side code is as follows:

```
[WebMethod]    
    public List<Referral_PrecertVO.DiagnosisCodes> GetDiagnosisCodes(string diagCode, string description)
    {
    var list = new List<Referral_PrecertVO.DiagnosisCodes>();

    list = objReferral_PrecertBL.GetDiagnosisCodes(diagCode, description);

    return list;
}
```